# How to select part of a text field using ms word macros

Tags: vba, ms-word, textfield

I am trying to build template invoices for Xero. Xero looks for specific fields in your **MS Word** template and inputs the variable assigned to that **text field** name in your given format. In word you can toggle the field code to view as just the field name:

```
«InvoiceNumber»
```

or the name with format:

```
{ MERGEFIELD InvoiceNumber \* MERGEFORMAT}
```

This outputs: `INV1234` successfully into the template. Now what I need to do is output just the last 4 characters.

[This post](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26249732/String-operations-on-MSWord-text-fields.html) seems to imply it must be done with a VBA. I put together a **macro** with **Visual Basic** in word and this is where I have hit trouble:

```
Sub InvoiceNumber()
    Dim MyInv As FormFields
        Set MyInv = ActiveDocument.FormFields
        If MyInv("Text1").Result = "InvoiceNumber" Then
            MyInv("Text1").CheckBox.Value = Right(MyInv("Text1"), 4)
        End If
End Sub
```

This returns with

> error 5941: The requested member of the selection does not exist

I am quite a beginner with VB macros in word, what am I doing wrong and how should I instead be trying to call the InvoiceNumber Field?

Answer (score 2):

Please try with the following solution:

```
Sub InvoiceNumber()
        Dim MyInv As Field
        Set MyInv = GetFieldByName("InvoiceNumber")

        If Not MyInv Is Nothing Then
            'do something with field result...
            'here... debug to Immediate window
            Debug.Print Right(MyInv.Result, 4)
        End If
End Sub

Function GetFieldByName(fName As String) As Field

    Dim F As Field
    For Each F In ActiveDocument.Fields
        'if not working try with (1) istead of (2) in line below
        If Split(Replace(F.Code, "  ", " "), " ")(2) = fName Then
            Set GetFieldByName = F
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next F
    Set GetFieldByName = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: The macro works well, fixes my error and normally it would output exactly what I am asking for, unfortunately it turns out the template reader in Xero does not communicate with it.. So I will need to find another way (probably in Xero API) to achieve this